# How do I use a class from a different partial class, but in the same namespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, class

I want to use a class that is in a certain public partial class, in another public partial class. Both of these classes are in the same namespace but I just can't figure out how to do it.

I have used `public static Color ThemeColor = Color.Lime;` and it works just fine in StartPage.cs, but not in Game.cs.

---

*StartPage.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public partial class App : Form
    {
        public static Color ThemeColor = Color.Lime;

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Game.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

namespace App
{
    public partial class Game : Form
    {
        public Game()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Console.WriteLine(ThemeColor);
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is the error I get:

> The name 'ThemeColor' does not exist in the current context.

What do I need to add or change to get this working?

Comment: You have declared `ThemeColor` as a static field in App so => `Console.WriteLine(App.ThemeColor)`.

Comment: Also, you should not [name a class the same as it's namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one).

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Wow, it was that simple. Thank you!

Comment: You are in App.Game, ThemeColor is defined in App.App. You can either reference it as App.App.ThemeColor or import it with a using statement, but I’d really suggest that you spend some time reviewing the basics of how classes work in C# - referring members of one form in another isn’t generally a good design, nor is making a class the same thing as its namespace.

Comment: It gave those names automaticly when I created the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static variable is inside the App class, soo...

```
App.ThemeColor
```